# How do you get the component's current native element?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that you can call React.findDOMNode(this), but is there another method? I'd like to know if there's a reference kept (and obviously available when the component is mounted).

Comment: Further reading has led me to a deprecated method "getDOMNode()". I'm curious what the rationale is for not having a property on ReactComponent that references the DOM element once it's mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React and refs have been a moving target for some time.

[Facebook has said](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) string refs are deprecated.

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and **are likely to be removed in one of the future releases**. If you're currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern instead.

Current best practice is callback refs. Ideally you'd manage component state with setState. However refs are necessary if you need to work with another lib or animations. See also: [ReactDOM.findDOMNode()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toddsby/a9h5379j/)

```
const HowdyPardner = React.createClass({
  _getHeaderEl: function( el ) {
    this.headerEl = el;
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.headerEl.textContent = 'YEEHAW';
  },
  render: function() {
   return (
     <h1 ref={this._getHeaderEl}>Howdy Pardner!</h1>
   ); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by current native element but :
You can use the refs.

```
class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.main.innerHTML = "Yep";
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div ref="main" >Hello World</div>
    )
  }
}
```

normaly, the code above show "Yep" to the screen.

just put a `ref` property to any element ex: `<div ref="main">Hello World</div>`, and you can access the ref in the componentDidMount with : `this.refs.main`

Comment: I noticed that ref callbacks are preferred over string refs. Is there really no way to get "this" as a native dom element (assuming it's already mounted)?

Comment: why are ref callbacks preferred ?

Comment: Note:
Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy, and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback refs are preferred. [Refs to Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)